# VHDL: Equality of std_logic_vector in combinational logic

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to write what I thought would be some simple combinational logic equations. It is for a CPLD that performs address decoding.
So I have an address bus: `a: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)` and want to test for a specific but partial (IO) address. (mytemp is signal of std_logic)

```
mytemp <= a(11 downto 2) == "1111111111";
```

Does not fly and I have no idea why. I have been searching for examples but everything I try does not work and gives syntax errors.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: the '==' I saw somewhere on the interweb but that should be '='.

Comment: first, what is this `==` thing? the equality operator is `=`. Second, equality returns a boolean, so declare `mytemp` accordingly.

Comment: Ok, but when I complete the expression with other std_logic inputs (control signals like IOREQ) I get "type of identifier "nIOREQ" does not agree with its usage as "boolean" type" for 'mytemp <= not nIOREQ and a(11 downto 2) = "1111111111";'

Comment: That's a different question. `boolean` and `std_logic`have historically been different types - allowing negative logic to be more easily expressed for example- but the restrictions are relaxed in VHDL-2008 if your tools support that. Meanwhile, `not nIOREQ` returns std_logic; `nIOREQ = '0'` returns boolean.

Comment: Ok, but how can I 'mix' a boolean and a std_logic in one expression?

Comment: You need to share the syntax errors you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

To clarify Brian's point, let's say you have a component something like this:

```
entity cpld is
  port
  (
    ...
    a : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    ...
    nIOREQ : out std_logic;
    ...
  );
end entity cpld;
```

Now, how can you use a sub-range of `a` to set `nIOREQ`?  Let me count the ways:

```
architecture rtl of cpld is
  signal mytemp : boolean;
  signal mytemp2 : std_logic;
begin
  -- One way, using a boolean intermediate
  mytemp <= a(11 downto 2) = "1111111111";
  nIOREQ <= '0' when mytemp else '1';

  -- Another way, using a std_logic intermediate
  mytemp2 <= '1' when a(11 downto 2) = "1111111111" else '0';
  nIOREQ <= not(mytemp2);

  -- Another way deriving it directly
  nIOREQ <= '0' when a(11 downto 2) = "1111111111" else '1';

  -- Another way to derive directly
  with a(11 downto 2) select
    nIOREQ <= '0' when "1111111111",
              '1' when others;

  -- Another direct method, using VHDL-2008's and reduction operator
  nIOREQ <= not(and a(11 downto 2));
end architecture rtl;
```

There are **lots** of ways to do it.  I haven't come close to exhausting the methods.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since mytemp is std_logic_vector you need an if statement to check the address:

```
if a(11 downto 2) = "1111111111" then
  mytemp <= '1';
else
  mytemp <= '0';
end if;
```

The above code needs to be inside a process. If you want a simple combinatorial statement then use:

```
mytemp <= '1' when a(11 downto 2) = "1111111111" else '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to Renato's is:

```
with a(11 downto 2) select
  mytemp <= '1' when "1111111111",
            '0' when others;
```

I prefer to use this type of construct for more complicated expressions because you don't run the risk of a priority encoder when one isn't needed or expected.

Answer (score 1):

In VHDL-2008, use the matching relational operators as they return std_logic when the input is std_logic_vector:

```
mytemp <= a(11 downto 2) ?= "1111111111";
```

Also since all of the values you are comparing against are '1', you could also use the following (also VHDL-2008):

```
mytemp <= and a(11 downto 2) ;
```